# I can't create subscriptions on google play. Upload APK

Tags: google-play

I don't understand why it won't let me create subscriptions or paid products in Google Play. The following screen appears
[Subscriptions screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFhnl.png)

However on the production screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJg2u.png)

Although the production channel is inactive, I don't understand why

I have already uploaded my production version

Comment: is your country supported for IAP and Subscription?